# Can't get script source in document.write

Tags: javascript, html

This is my code:

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Fullscreen</button>
<script>
function myFunction() {
var myWindow = window.open("", "myWindow", "width=500,height=400");
myWindow.document.write("<script 
src=‘ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js’><\/script> 
<script src=‘ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/swfobject/2.2/swfobject.js’> 
<\/script><script type=‘text/javascript’>var 
resizeOwnEmulator=function(width,height){var emulator=$('#emulator');emulator.css('width',width);emulator.css('height',height)}$(function(){function embed(){var emulator=$('#emulator');if(emulator){var flashvars={system:'gb',url:'/uploads/2/6/7/6/26766876/pokemon-gold.zip'};var params={};var attributes={};params.allowscriptaccess='sameDomain';params.allowFullScreen='true';params.allowFullScreenInteractive='true';swfobject.embedSWF('/uploads/3/8/8/3/38833005/nesbox.swf','emulator','640','480','11.2.0','/flash/bin/expressInstall.swf',flashvars,params,attributes)}}embed()});<\/script>");
myWindow.document.close();
var p = document.createElement("p")
p.innerHTML = "This is the source window!";
opener.document.querySelector("body").appendChild(p)
}
</script>
```

I'm trying to get the popup window to display the flash file, but it just returns this in the dev console:

```
swfobject.js%E2%80%99:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a 
status of 404 (Not Found)
jquery.min.js%E2%80%99:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with 
a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

It might have something to do with

```
<script src=‘ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js’>
```

I might need double quotes for that, but I can't put double quotes in the document.write("")

Comment: Are those single quotes or back ticks? Single quotes should work, back ticks certainly won't. You can also use double quotes by escaping them with a preceding back slash.

Comment: The errors in console are telling you precisely what's wrong - those aren't full URLs. Start them with `https://`. Also, don't use backticks, use single or double quotes (both are fine in HTML attributes). Use a forward slash to escape a character – `"This is a \"String\""`.

Comment: Change your quotes around the src and type arttrubutes to double quotes with a forward slash to escape them: ```\"``` and you also have to include a protocol in the src attributes: ```<script src=\"https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js\"><\/script>```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I might need double quotes for that

You can use:

- U+0022 : QUOTATION MARK
- U+0027 : APOSTROPHE {APL quote}

You can't, but are trying to, use:

- U+2018 : LEFT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK {single turned comma quotation mark}
- U+2019 : RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK {single comma quotation mark}

This is typically caused by trying to write code with a word processor instead of a text editor.

> but I can't put double quotes in the document.write("")

You can. `"` characters can be escaped as `\"` in a string literal in JS.

Comment: OK, I no longer get any errors but it just doesn't work.

Comment: @user3125845 — Does your browser support Flash? Most don't these days.

Comment: Yeah it works normally. I'm getting the errors again. I have <script src=\”ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js\”><\/script><script src=\”ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/swfobject/2.2/swfobject.js\”><\/script> and that doesn't work. Ive tried https:// or as it is supposed to be, //